# Can 2 for loops be run simultaneously, looping one after the other?

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, mpi, theory

I was just wondering, how would you create a loop such that each iteration occurs one after the other? I am aware that multi threading is a thing, and I am familiar with it. One thing I cannot figure out is how to run one loop after another.

For example, say I had 2 functions:

```
def loop_a():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("a")

def loop_b():
    while True:
        print("b")
```

**How do i get the output to be `ababababababababa`, even with the `time.sleep(1)` present in the first function?**

I am using **mpi4py**, and was wondering if there was any way to do this using this library. **My actual program requires messages to be sent between functions.** Otherwise, using any other python libraries such as `multiprocessing` should be fine.

Is there a way to do this using **threading**?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an XY-Problem. Why do you want this output? What is the actual *behavior* you need to achieve? Please [edit] your question to include more details on the dependencies between work done in the loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import asyncio

q = asyncio.Queue()

async def loop_a(q):
  for i in range(10):
    value = await q.get()
    print(value)

async def loop_b(q):
  for i in range(10):
    await q.put("a")
    print("b")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(loop_a(q), loop_b(q)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use corutines:

```
import asyncio

q = asyncio.Queue()

async def loop_a(q):
  for i in range(10):
    value = await q.get()
    print(value)

async def loop_b(q):
  for i in range(10):
    await q.put("a")
    print("b")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(loop_a(q), loop_b(q)))
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/NearUltimateLightweightprocess)

The only think is that the order of execution is not guaranteed unless you sync them somehow.

Comment: This is just an example though. To explain, the functions may have `while` loops instead of `for` loops. And more complicated things (such as message passing between each function will occur). I dont think this solution fits my needs so lemme change the question

Comment: how exactly would i do that (while loop included)

Comment: I updated it. I would do it with corutines. I did not checked on the comunication stuff from the question.

Comment: running this code prints either `aaaaabbbbb` or `bbbbbaaaaa`. It doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to the first part of your question - how to run processes in parallel so that each process waits for the previous one has been finished to start working on tasks. I didn't address a message passing aspect here as it seems a bit vague to me and could be implemented differently based on the problem statement. In this example, we create and run three workers which emulate execution by simple time delays. The code snippets should be saved into a single file which can be run from the command line.

We start by importing the required modules:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time

from multiprocessing import Process, Event
```

and implementing a `WorkerQueue` class. This class keeps workers in the right order and is responsible for starting and terminating them. The communication between workers is implemented using events. Each worker has **other_ready** and **ready** `Event` fields which indicate the accomplish statuses of a previous worker and the current worker, accordingly. Note, if there is only one worker in the queue, its **other_ready** and **ready** are the same.

```
class WorkerQueue(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._workers = []

    def add_worker(self, worker):

        if self._workers:
            worker.other_ready = self._workers[-1].ready
            self._workers[0].other_ready = worker.ready
        else:
            worker.other_ready = worker.ready

        self._workers.append(worker)

    def start_workers(self):

        if not self._workers:
            return

        self._workers[0].other_ready.set()

        for w in self._workers:
            w.start()

    def stop_workers(self):

        for w in self._workers:
            w.join()
```

Then, we implement the worker itself by inheriting from the `Process` class. Note, it's also possible to use `threading` instead of `multiprocessing`. In this case, the only thing gets changed is the `Worker` parent class, `Thread` instead of `Process`.

```
class Worker(Process):

    def __init__(self, delay, name=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.delay = delay
        self.other_ready = Event()
        self.other_ready.set()
        self.ready = Event()
        self.stop = Event()

    def run(self):

        while not self.stop.is_set():

            try:
                self.other_ready.wait()

                t = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                print('Started:', self.name, t, flush=True)

                time.sleep(self.delay)

                t = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                print('Finished:', self.name, t, flush=True)
            except:
                break

            self.other_ready.clear()
            self.ready.set()

    def join(self, timeout=None):
        self.stop.set()
        super().join(timeout)
```

Here you see, each worker waits for the previous one to be ready before starting to execute commands. By default, the **other_ready** is set so that we won't hit a deadlock in the case of a single worker in the queue.

Finally, we implement a `main` function where we define workers, adding them to the worker queue, and starting them.

```
def main():
    first = Worker(delay=1, name='first')
    second = Worker(delay=3, name='second')
    third = Worker(delay=2, name='third')

    queue = WorkerQueue()

    for w in (first, second, third):
        queue.add_worker(w)

    queue.start_workers()

    try:

        # The main infinite loop, do something useful:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        queue.stop_workers()
```

Don't forget to add the following lines to the end of the file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, it's ready to be saved to a file, say `proc_queue.py`, which you can run from the command line to see the results:

```
$ python3 proc_queue.py 
Started: first 16:04:09
Finished: first 16:04:10
Started: second 16:04:10
Finished: second 16:04:13
Started: third 16:04:13
Finished: third 16:04:15
Started: first 16:04:15
Finished: first 16:04:16
Started: second 16:04:16
Finished: second 16:04:19
Started: third 16:04:19
Finished: third 16:04:21
^C
```

It might be a bit overcomplicated but it's the only solution I could come up with. If you know a better approach I'd be happy to learn about it :)

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode:

```
main()
1. set lock for loop1
2. start loop1 on background thread
3. start loop2 on background thread
4. wait

loop1()
1. do the following forever:
2.    acquire lock for loop1
3.    print 'a'
4.    release lock for loop2

loop2()
1. do the following forever:
2.    acquire lock for loop2
3.    print 'b'
4.    release lock for loop1
```

You can implement the lock as a shared memory variable or as a loop waiting to get a message from your peer or whatever. Acquiring the lock would mean blocking or spin-locking (polling) until the lock is ready; releasing the lock would be setting the shared variable appropriately or sending the right message to the right peers.

Edit: based on a comment, here's a more full development of loop1() and loop2() using one of many available implementation strategies:

```
(shared lock in global scope)

main()
1. lock = 1
2. start loop1 on background thread
3. start loop2 on background thread
4. wait

loop1()
1. do the following forever
2.    loop until lock = 1
3.    print 'a'
4.    lock = 2

loop2()
1. do the following forever
2.    loop until lock = 2
3.    print 'b'
4.    lock = 1
```

This implementation uses spin locks and relies on a thread-safe shared variable `lock` to coordinate work. Spin locks may or may not be suitable for your application. You can use these in conjunction with some blocking mechanism to cut down on processing at the cost of some delay in processing.

The key is that the `lock` is stateful and (should) only be acquired by the right thread. You can do the same thing with message passing if each thread is made "aware" of the "next" thread and messages it when done... and then all threads wait to get messaged.

```
main()
1. start loop1 on background thread
2. start loop2 on background thread
3. message loop1
4. wait

loop1()
1. do the following forever
2.    loop until message received
3.    print 'a'
4.    message loop2

loop2()
1. do the following forever
2.    loop until message received
3.    print 'b'
4.    message loop1
```

Comment: It just doesn't work despite it looks pretty straightforward. This is the first idea that came into my mind so I tested it first. The problem is one thread can acquire the lock multiple times before the second one does. Also, you cannot guarantee the order of thread execution.

Comment: @constt No, it does work if you implement it right. You are missing the "for loop1" and "for loop2" part. The "acquire" method should only acquire the lock if the lock is in the right state. The lock can be "available for loop1" and "available for loop2", and can only be acquired by the respective loops in those cases. This fixes the "multiple acquisition" problem and guarantees deterministic ordering (note how the Main() program sets the state of the lock to "available for loop1"). That's the key. Don't just have a 0/1 shared counter or an "available" broadcast; make it stateful.

Comment: (if you don't want the loops to know about each other, fine; implement the lock as a class that you register with and then simply release the lock to make it available for the next registered loop.)

Comment: OK, now I see, thanks. My comment was about the very first pseudocode you posted. I mistakenly thought you tried to solve the problem with only one lock shared between threads. Thanks for explanations!